# Increasing index of array doesn't work when it's stored as global variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to update array index as function incIndex runs:

```
const arr=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let index = 0;
let arrIndex = arr[index]
const incIndex = () => index++;
```

but it only works this way

```
console.log(arr[index]) // 1
incIndex();
console.log(arr[index]) // 2
```

but when I do

```
console.log(arrIndex) // 1
incIndex();
console.log(arrIndex) // 1
```

I still get element of index 0. Does anyone know how to fix it so I can use 2nd way?

Comment: The `arrIndex` variable stores the *value* which `arr[index]` evaluated to during the initialisation of the variable. It is not an alias/pointer/reference to the property. It does not-reevaluate the `arr[index]` expression every time it is used. You'd need a function for that.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using a for loop

```
const arr=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

where the i variable in the loop would be the increasing index

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

This one copies the value of the first element of the array to a new variable.

```
let arrIndex = arr[index]
```

You can't expect it to be changed when changing the index.

Answer (score 0):

`arrIndex` value will be always the same if you don't replace the value after the first declaration. (Also you are missing a semicolon at the end)

If you set `arrIndex = arr[index]`, it will be equal to the value of `arr[index]` at the moment you assign it (1). It is not a dynamic value.

For a dynamic value you maybe can create a function but it doesn't worth it. It's better to use arr[index]

```
function returnDynamicValue(){
    return arr[index];
}
```

And then

```
console.log(returnDynamicValue());
incIndex();
console.log(returnDynamicValue());
```